# Form validation in symfony 4 doesn't work

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have created an Entity `Testme` and generated the crud file with `bin/console make:crud` and try to add a validation rule to the form but it doesn't work:

My Entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TestmeRepository")
 */
class Testme
{
 /**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $description;

....
```

The form:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Testme;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class TestmeType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('description')
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Testme::class,
    ]);
}
}
```

The controller action:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="testme_edit", methods="GET|POST")
 */
public function edit(Request $request, Testme $testme): Response
{
    $form = $this->createForm(TestmeType::class, $testme);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('testme_edit', ['id' => $testme->getId()]);
    }

    return $this->render('testme/edit.html.twig', [
        'testme' => $testme,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

If the `name` field is blank, the validation error is correctly show when creating a new entity, but when I edit it and empty the `name` field, I get an `InvalidArgumentException` on the `$form->handleRequest($request);` line:

> Expected argument of type "string", "NULL" given.

What am I missing?

EDIT: all the code have been generated by the `make:Entity` and `make:crud` commands, I only added the `@Assert\NotBlank()` on the `$name` property.

Comment: You should remove type hinting in your setters in your entities or make argument defaults to null

Comment: yes, removing type hinting works. I imagined that the form validate the input before updating the object and I don't understand why this problem doesn't appear when creating a new object... Anyway, please answer my question so I can validate your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Form and posted data binding is applied *before* any validation. If you typehint the setters/adders you'll run in this kind of scenarios.

From my POV you should not modify your "model" code in order to satisfy third party code (form component, here) as you can run into possible issues like wrong usage of a method (if a value need to be there, the only possible way to ensure a "not null" requirement is to avoid accepting null; validator itself will do nothing as soon as you "forget" to invoke `valid` on the object and, even in that case, you still have a valid *and* flushable object).

Instead you should bind DTOs or ValueObjects to your form. These objects can accept any kind of value you want (basically the value you expect and null). Then you can perform validation and, for instance, with a "command" (not a symfony one, a "command" in the DDD "concept") you can populate and perform other "data passage" or manipulation to *real* entities.

Even if ste's answer will make it work, is conceptually wrong as expose your code to "domain risks" explained above in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove type hinting in your setters in your entities or make argument defaults to null.

Maybe the form component doesn't update fields (i.e. calling setXXX) if they are not changed (as when in case of a new object).

Validation is done in the object as yours constraints (i.e. @Assert annotations) are defined there.

You can validate directly in the form using constrains. See https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/without_class.html#adding-validation